# Python: Two functions, multiple arguments, cannot get the csv to print

Tags: python, function

```
def clean_age_data(age):
def make_csv_line(first,last,age):
    return'%s, %s, %s' % first,last,age
##print (clean_age_data('9years'))##this works
print (make_csv_line('Jason','Young','20yearsold'))
```

So above are two functions that are supposed to print csv string that will have the age entry cleaned to a proper number, (that 20yearsold will return 20). That part works perfectly. I am having trouble implementing the functions together and getting it to print out. The above code should print out 'Jason Young 20'. I just started coding and I've spent the past week trying to get it to work. I have looked up a lot site on how to implement functions but to no avail. Anything would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more helpful if you showed us precisely what troubles you are heaving, like error messages.

A quick scan of your source reveals at least one problem.  I'm guessing you are getting `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`:

```
return'%s, %s, %s' % first,last,age
```

That needs to be

```
return '%s, %s, %s' % (first, last, age)
```

The argument to a format string needs to be a `tuple` in your case.

Python [does allow other types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), like `dict`...

```
"%(hello)s %(world)s" % { "hello": "Hi", "world": "there!" }
```

...or a single non-tuple argument if the format string only requires a single argument:

```
"%s" % foo
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the csv to return by adding the parentheses. I don't think ill ever forget that again. Now to get the whole string to return invalid if the age comes back invalid.